# filter data for more than 5k items through pnpjs SPFx

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience, pnpjs

Here is the situation :

1. I have a list with 50k items.
2. I have to get data from that list with a filter on status column (Status = true).
3. So basically there are items with status true/false.
4. When I will filter (Status = true) the items returned are 18k.

How will I filter data for above condition through PnP JS SPFx.

```
 await sp.web.lists
        .getByTitle("listName")
        .items.select("ID", "Status", "Title")
        .filter("Status eq 'True'").get();
```

This is not working.

Answer (score 1):

This is known limitation of SP PnP JS / SharePoint REST APIs.

You cannot add filter on SharePoint list items where returned items/results will be more than 5000.

You have to get all SharePoint list items first & then apply client side filtering using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Quote [from the official documentation](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/items/):

> Using the items collection's getAll method you can get all of the
> items in a list **regardless of the size of the list**:

**Example**

```
const allItems: any[] = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("BigList").items.select("Title").filter("Title eq 'Test'").getAll();
```

In your case, this is the code that should work:

```
await sp.web.lists
        .getByTitle("listName")
        .items.select("ID", "Status", "Title")
        .filter("Status eq 'True'").getAll();
```

If this code does not work, make sure your list has indexes for the Status and Title columns.

Answer (score 0):

What the official documentation doesn't say, it's limited to 2000 items by default. You can check the information of the getAll() method.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To avoid view threshold, use filter by indexed field (no more than 20 indexes in list). More info [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/community/large-lists-large-libraries-in-sharepoint).

Also, you can use Search. It doesn't care about list view threshold at all.